How can I calculate $\int_{R^2}\; \exp (-x^2-xy-y^2)\,dxdy$ this Riemann Integral.
How can I calculate $\int_{R^2}\; \exp (-x^2-xy-y^2)\,dxdy$ this Riemann Integral. Knowing that $\int_{R^2}\; \exp (-x^2-y^2)\,dxdy = π$ .

What's dA(x,y)?

@lisyarus I think that is dxdy

Do you mean $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^(-x^2-xy-y^2)dxdy$?

Using polar coordinates:
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2-xy-y^2}dxdy  & =\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty} re^{-r^2-r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta}\ \ drd\theta \\ &=-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-r^2-r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta} \ \ d(-r^2)d\theta \\ & = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1+\cos\theta\sin\theta} \ d\theta \\&=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt3}
 \end{align}

If $M=\left[ \begin{array}{cc}1&1/2\\1/2&1\end{array}\right]$ we have $(x,y)M\left( \begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right)=x^2+xy+y^2.$
Writing $ M=U^{-1}\mathrm{diag}(1/2,3/2)U$ where $U$ is an orthogonal matrix, the change of variable $\left(\begin{array}{c}X\\Y\end{array}\right)=U\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right)$ gives $dXdY=dxdy$ since $\det U=\pm 1.$ The integral becomes $$\int_Re^{-X^2/2}dX\times \int_Re^{-3Y^2/2}dY=\sqrt{2\pi}\times \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\sqrt{3}}.$$
